# How to avoid using a package in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have been using Angular Universal SSR (Angular 12) with Express and [@agm/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/core) (Google Maps). I get this error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined at WindowRef.getNativeWindow
```

this happens because @agm/core is trying to use window and this is not defined in server side.

So my question is, **how can i disable this package in server side for not get this type of errors?**.

For the integration you have to import @agm/core at app.module like this:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: ['YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'],
})
```

And then you will be able to use the agm-map component.